# How to install arbor.js

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, eclipse

I am following the documentation: http://arborjs.org/introduction and trying to install arbor in order to get some data visualised. In Eclipse Juno, I have created a Static Web Project and added an HTML file in Web Content. Through the tutorial in the link above, I am supposed to do the following steps:

```
   1- Get jQuery and add the file at lib/arbor.js to your path somewhere.
   2- include them in your HTML:

        <script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="path/to/arbor.js"></script>
```

Could anyone please guide me how to do these two steps. I have never worked on neither Arobor nor Javascript. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well you put those two lines in your html file and then where it says src="path/to/jquery.min.js" its the path to the file, so usually people put them in a folder either called "js" or "lib" but its up to you what you call the folder or if you even have a folder...

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Unfortunately I could not see the expected outputs. I also added the other codes to display a node but nothing appeared. Do you have any idea what else can be a problem?

Comment: Oh, didn't see your comment until now... and you're welcome :)